# How to clear Carthage cache?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, carthage

I use *Carthage* dependencies manager in my iOS projects and I am wondering what is the best way to clean its cache in case some issues with update occur

Answer (score 171, accepted):

The solution from [here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/443) helped me,
we should call it like:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit
```

Comment: or add sudo before this command to make it:
`sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit`

Comment: There's should be no need for sudo since ~/ means it's in the user's home directory, unless potentially they ran carthage as root or something...

Comment: also, maybe just my version, but:  `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/carthage`

Comment: also keep in mind Carthage will "find a valid cache" when the output directory already contains the built framework

Comment: In my case (version 0.38.0), I have both `~/Library/Caches/carthage` and `~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit`.