# Can't not fetch google/promises by carthage update

Tags: carthage

Can't fetch google/promises by `carthage update`

```
carthage update
```

Output:

> *** Fetching promises
>
> A shell task (`/usr/bin/env git fetch --prune --quiet https://github.com/google/promises.git refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` (launched in /Users/p000666/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/promises)) failed with exit code 1

Steps:

1. Add the following to **Cartfile**:
   `#github "google/promises"`
2. Add the following to **Cartfile.resolved**
   `#github "google/promises" "1.2.8"`
3. Then, run `carthage update`

Could you please help me suggest the solution to fetch `#github "google/promises"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the carthage cache resolved this for me (for a different repo). See: [How to clear Carthage cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504896/how-to-clear-carthage-cache)

This problem seems to be related to an open issue with Carthage: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2786